# DataGrid to Observable collection of custom class object issue

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I'm somewhat of a novice, so I'm pretty flaky when it comes to binding.  I've searched for quite some time, but I simply cannot find any examples that get me to where I need.

I have a DataGrid bound to an observable collection.  It is a collection of a custom class that contains several properties (one of which is, itself an observable collection).  The user inputs text into the DataGrid and it updates the Observable collection.  I would like users to be able to right click on a row in the DataGrid and get a context menu with items generated from the observable collection property of the item in the parent observable collection.

For simplicity, my DataGrid is bound to InputItemList, which is an Observable Collection of InputItem.

InputItemList as ObservableCollection(Of InputItem)

InputItem has properties:
Part_Number as String
Drawing_List as ObservableCollection(Of DrawingItem)

DrawingItem has properties:
Revision as String
Drawing_Path as String

The DataGrid is bound via ItemsSource to InputItemList, and is working properly.
For the life of me, I cannot create a series of menu items that are bound to the Drawing_List collection

Here's a simplified version of my XAML with ??? where I need help with the binding:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="mw_DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource InputItemList}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Part_Number}" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" Header=""/>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Obsolete Revision" ItemsSource=????>
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Path=Revision}"/>
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{StaticResource cmdOpenObsPDF}" />
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Drawing_Path}" />
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property on your view model, of type InputItem, that represents the currently selected row. Name it for example CurrentlySelectedInputItem

Then bind that to the DataGrids SelectedItem.

Then bind the itemsource you are wanting to:

```
<MenuItem Header="Open Obsolete Revision" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentlySelectedItem.DrawingList}">
```

Not 100% sure of the menu Item usage - but that is how to bind to the drawing_List you are after, you should be able to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to do it all in xaml?

Comment: Possibly - never tried though. Guess you would make the ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.DrawingList, ElementName=mw_DataGrid}" or ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DrawingList, ElementName=mw_DataGrid.SelectedItem}"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
I actually had to do this once already and totally forgot!

Apparently there's some difficulty searching back through the tree with context menus.
I do not remember the full explanation, but here's the XAML that works for me:

```xml
<MenuItem Header="Open Obsolete Revision" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem.DrawingList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
```